# PHP JS GET parameter different coding in Chrome and IE

Tags: php, javascript, url, encoding

I have a page with input field and JS function to relad with with input value as _GET parameter.

```
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
</head>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
var urlBasePath = '/webpage/';
function addUserCategory()
{
    name=document.getElementById('userMenuInput').value;
    parent.dhxLayoutMenu.cells('a').attachURL(urlBasePath + 'file.php?name='+name);
}

</script>
<div class="userMenuHeader">
<input size="25" id="userMenuInput" class="userMenuInput" type="text" name="nazwaFiltra">
<input type="button" value="save" class="userMenuButtonSave" onclick="addUserCategory();">
</div>
```

When I type the polish characters I have different calls in Chrome and IE.
What I see in access.log for IE call is:

```
name.php?name=z\xb3\xb9
```

while after call from Chrome I see:

```
name.php?name=z%C5%82%C4%85
```

and that is desired call.
**How can I force IE to produce the same coding as Chrome?**

Regards,
Ludwik

SOLUTION is to enclose use encodeURI() function on variable 'name':

```
        parent.dhxLayoutMenu.cells('a').attachURL(urlBasePath + 'file.php?name='+encodeURI(name));
```

And that solves the problem.

Comment: I think this is similar to your situation but with Firefox: [Issue with character encoding in POST requests sent with Firefox](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12463800/1693859)